# Make an Ajax request in Yii 2.0?

Tags: ajax, yii2

Right, i only want a very simple ajax request to get this working. im new with yii 2.0 framework you see.

in my view index.php:

```
  function sendFirstCategory(){

        var test = "this is an ajax test";

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/ajax') ?>',
            type: 'POST',
             data: { test: test },
             success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);

             }
         });
    }
```

Now when i call this i assume that it should go to my CasesController to an action called actionAjax.

```
public function actionAjax()
{
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
        $test = "Ajax Worked!";
    }else{
        $test = "Ajax failed";
    }

    return $test;
}
```

EDIT::

Ok great, so this works up to here. I get back the alert that pops up with the new value for $test. However i want to be able to access this value in php as ultimately i will be accessing data from a database and ill be wanting to query and do various other things.

So how do i now use this variable in php instead of just the pop up alert()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can access the post data in controller:

```
public function actionAjax()
{
    if(isset(Yii::$app->request->post('test'))){
        $test = "Ajax Worked!";
        // do your query stuff here
    }else{
        $test = "Ajax failed";
        // do your query stuff here
    }

    // return Json    
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 //Controller file code
public function actionAjax()
        {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post('test');
            if (isset($data)) {
                $test = "Ajax Worked!";
            } else {
                $test = "Ajax failed";
            }
            return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
        }




//_form.php code 
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#mausers-user_email").focusout(function () {
                    sendFirstCategory();
                });
            });

        function sendFirstCategory() {
            var test = "this is an ajax test";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/ajax')  ; ?>",
                data: {test: test},
                success: function (test) {
                    alert(test);
                },
                error: function (exception) {
                    alert(exception);
                }
            })
            ;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include js this way in your view file:

```
$script = <<< JS
    $('#el').on('click', function(e) {
        sendFirstCategory();
    });
    JS;

    $this->registerJs($script, $position);
```

// where $position can be View::POS_READY (the default), 
// or View::POS_HEAD, View::POS_BEGIN, View::POS_END

```
function sendFirstCategory(){

        var test = "this is an ajax test";

        $.ajax({
           url: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/ajax') ?>",
           data: {test: test},
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data)
           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i though the code would work i just didn't know how to get the URl. thanks!!

Comment: in fact actually, i wonder if you could help me again, i will update my question for you to read.